# Is there any open source DVD duplication software like Nero?

Tags: dvd, iso-image, burning, nero

Nero Essentials isn't working right and I wondered if there was anything open source that I could use.  I need to duplicate a DVD that I have authored - not a data disc a "real" dvd (with vob files, etc.)  CDBurnerXP did not have this.

Or, if I create an .iso is that the same thing when I burn it back to my duplicate?

Thanks.

edit:  is creating an iso and burning it to a new dvd the same as duplicating a DVD in something like NERO or is DVD duplication something else?

Comment: If it's a video DVD, with the standard video DVD filesystem structure, and not copy protected, you can just copy the files as you would anything else.  Now you may run into problems if your original DVD is a dual-layer and you need to copy down to a single-layer - you need to recode the video in that case.  DVD Shrink, if you can find it, may be the easiest to use if you are in that situation (Handbrake may also be able to do this).

Answer (score 3):

[ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/) will enable you to create an .iso of a disk and then burn that .iso to many more disks time and time again. This is basically what nero does.

and in response to your edit, yes.

Comment: 4 years later... Still works for me!

Answer (score 2):

I've always been a fan of [InfraRecorder](http://infrarecorder.org/), which seems to do what you want and is open-source.

Answer (score 1):

An ISO is what you would burn back to your duplicate.

See this [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_image) article for a little bit more information:

> An ISO image is an archive file (also known as a disc image) of an optical disc in a format defined by the International Organization for Standardization (ISO). This format is supported by many software vendors. ISO image files typically have a file extension of .iso.

Comment: Does this mean that if I create the .iso of my master and burn it back to my new DVD that that is the same thing as having software that duplicates the DVD?  Is that what a dvd duplicator is doing behind the scenes?

Comment: @johnny - yes, that's exactly what a DVD (or CD) duplicator is doing.

Comment: Well, it is - and it isn't.  As long as you're talking NON-DRM source DVD it is.  Add DRM and it's a different story.  Commercial DVD duplicators deal with the DRM issues (legally or otherwise).

Comment: @hotei - I should have included that. In this case as the DVD is self authored I didn't think it necessary to mention it.